# AWS Lambda Could not find MyFunction.deps.json on .NET Core 3.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, f#, aws-sam

I've created a simple lambda project in F# and successfully deployed the lambda version which works fine online. But the local testing with `sam local invoke` doesn't work and throws the following error:

> `{"errorType":"LambdaException","errorMessage":"Could not find the required 'MyFunction.deps.json'.  This file should be present at the root of the deployment package."}`

I found the same error on stackoverflow and some github issue but I couldn't fix it by setting read permissions for the file. Here is the `sam build` command with the debug mode.
Interesting is that it says `... zipping:   adding: MyFunction.deps.json (deflated 77%)` and I can't find the .zip file which the log says the command should have created `Lambda project successfully packaged: /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/MyFunction.zip`. Can someone point me to a fix for this issue?

```
Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
'build' command is called
No Parameters detected in the template
1 resources found in the template
Found Serverless function with name='MyFunction' and CodeUri='./src/MyFunction/'
No Parameters detected in the template
Building function 'MyFunction'
Loading workflow module 'aws_lambda_builders.workflows'
Registering workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'NodejsNpmBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='nodejs', dependency_manager='npm', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'RubyBundlerBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='ruby', dependency_manager='bundler', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'GoDepBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='dep', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'GoModulesBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='modules', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'JavaGradleWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='gradle', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'JavaMavenWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='maven', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'DotnetCliPackageBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='dotnet', dependency_manager='cli-package', application_framework=None)'
Registering workflow 'CustomMakeBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='provided', dependency_manager=None, application_framework=None)'
Found workflow 'DotnetCliPackageBuilder' to support capabilities 'Capability(language='dotnet', dependency_manager='cli-package', application_framework=None)'
Running workflow 'DotnetCliPackageBuilder'
Running DotnetCliPackageBuilder:GlobalToolInstall
Installing Amazon.Lambda.Tools Global Tool
executing dotnet: ['dotnet', 'tool', 'install', '-g', 'Amazon.Lambda.Tools']

Error installing probably due to already installed. Attempt to update to latest version.
executing dotnet: ['dotnet', 'tool', 'update', '-g', 'Amazon.Lambda.Tools']
Tool 'amazon.lambda.tools' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '4.3.0').
DotnetCliPackageBuilder:GlobalToolInstall succeeded
Running DotnetCliPackageBuilder:RunPackageAction
Running `dotnet lambda package` in /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/src/MyFunction
executing dotnet: ['dotnet', 'lambda', 'package', '--output-package', '/home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/MyFunction.zip']
Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (4.3.0)
Project Home: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet

Executing publish command
Deleted previous publish folder
... invoking 'dotnet publish', working folder '/home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/src/MyFunction/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish'
... dotnet publish --output "/home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/src/MyFunction/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish" --configuration "Release" --framework "netcoreapp3.1" /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained false 
... publish: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.1+52cd83677 for .NET
... publish: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
... publish:   Determining projects to restore...
... publish:   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
... publish:   MyFunction -> /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/src/MyFunction/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/MyFunction.dll
... publish:   MyFunction -> /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/src/MyFunction/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx MyFunction.deps.json).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx MyFunction.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx FSharp.Core.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx MyFunction.pdb).
Changed permissions on published file (chmod +rx MyFunction.runtimeconfig.json).
Zipping publish folder /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/src/MyFunction/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish to /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/MyFunction.zip
Creating directory /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/.aws-sam/build/MyFunction
... zipping:   adding: MyFunction.deps.json (deflated 77%)
... zipping:   adding: MyFunction.dll (deflated 67%)
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.dll (deflated 46%)
... zipping:   adding: FSharp.Core.dll (deflated 69%)
... zipping:   adding: Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll (deflated 46%)
... zipping:   adding: MyFunction.pdb (deflated 30%)
... zipping:   adding: MyFunction.runtimeconfig.json (deflated 23%)
... zipping:   adding: tr/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 56%)
... zipping:   adding: ko/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 58%)
... zipping:   adding: fr/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 57%)
... zipping:   adding: cs/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 56%)
... zipping:   adding: it/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 57%)
... zipping:   adding: de/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 57%)
... zipping:   adding: zh-Hant/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 53%)
... zipping:   adding: pl/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 57%)
... zipping:   adding: ja/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 59%)
... zipping:   adding: pt-BR/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 56%)
... zipping:   adding: ru/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 62%)
... zipping:   adding: zh-Hans/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 54%)
... zipping:   adding: es/FSharp.Core.resources.dll (deflated 56%)
Created publish archive (/home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/MyFunction.zip).
Lambda project successfully packaged: /home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/MyFunction.zip
DotnetCliPackageBuilder:RunPackageAction succeeded

Build Succeeded

Built Artifacts  : .aws-sam/build
Built Template   : .aws-sam/build/template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided
```

Comment: Can you let us know what version of the SAM CLI you have installed? (`sam --version`)

Comment: @petey SAM CLI, version 0.53.0

Comment: just tried with version SAM CLI, version 1.10.0 - didn't help either

Comment: yea...0.53 is super old. Perhaps open the zip file and see where the file is vs where is it is expected?

Comment: I can't find the zip file at all which the output suggests is being created. The new version doesn't help either.

Comment: `/home/matthiasherrmann/aws/MyFunction/.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/MyFunction.zip`